# spark-jms-receiver loading making only one consumer busy

Tags: apache-spark, jms, spark-streaming, partitioning

I have a JMS Custom receiver for spark, and data published by a third party. Currently with that I can see only one consumer running which results in one spark executor getting used, due to that I am getting GC over head error after some time.

how to make multiple consumers so that data can be processed by multiple executors ?

I tried by re-partitioning after reading the Dsreams but producer is writing bit faster, hence after some point of time more records get collected at the single consumer and it throws GC overhead memory error.